# Liberty profile server with the name 'worklight' does not exist

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have change my workspace path in my eclipse, but after that, there is an error : Liberty profile server with the name 'worklight' does not exist.

How to setting my liberty profile server?

Answer (score 2):

I believe one of the following will help:

1. From the workspace, delete the MobileFirstServerConfig folder and restart Eclipse
2. From Eclipse, open the Projects view and delete the "MobileFirst Development Server" folder and restart Eclipse

If you're using Worklight and not MobileFirst, then you'll see the same names, just with "worklight".

Comment: Thank you for your help Idan Adar

Comment: i tried the way u provide but not work, the error as following: Liberty server with the name 'null' does not exist. Any idea how to set it up? thanks